# Timeline-wise, is it safe to plan attending the SODA conference if I apply for positions this year?

Tags: united-states, computer-science, job-search, job, faculty-application

I am applying for faculty positions in the US this year (in computer science).

Ideally, I would want to attend the SODA conference (January 5th-8th) and was wondering if it is safe to assume that on-site interviews are likely to start at a later date.

The reason why I ask is that the early-registration deadline ends December 2nd, probably before I'll know which (or how many) universities would want to interview me.

Comment: Would you mind either removing the name of the conference or explaning if this very conference is somehow different to other conferences? Keep in mind that a well-known conference to, say, US computer scientists may not be known to, say, Africal gender scientists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should be aware that on-campus CS faculty interviews have *already* started.  Yes, yes, I know that even the earliest application deadlines are still several weeks away, but at least in some departments (like mine), stellar candidates can be (and have been) invited to interview well before the application deadline.

That said, you should not worry at all about interviews colliding with SODA, for two reasons.  First, as Buffy says, most North American universities are on winter break that week; holding a faculty interview when none of the faculty are in the building, and many are out of town, would be pointless.

But more importantly, if a department invites you to interview for a faculty position, they will work with you to find a date when you are available to travel.  No sensible (North American) department is going to *both* devote the time and money and energy to fly you out for an interview *and* insist that the interview happen on one specific date.  If someone does suggest an interview on January 7, you can quite reasonably respond that you are attending an important conference that week, and ask for a different interview date.  If they really want you, they'll accommodate your schedule.

Remember that departments want their faculty to succeed; in particular, they *want* their faculty to be visibly active within their research communities.  The fact that you are attending SODA works in your favor, even *if* it makes scheduling slightly more complicated.

tl;dr: Yes, it's safe to register for SODA.

[I've served on faculty recruiting committees for at least 15 of the last 20 years.  I've also attended SODA every year since 1994.  See you there!]

Comment: Clearly I have applied to a couple of insensible departments, because they always paid for my trip and were generally *highly* inflexible about dates (but this was in Europe, so YMMV).

Comment: Yeah.  European hiring processes are... different.

Answer (score 1):

The conference window is pretty small. I'm not sure why you'd be concerned. You should get, from any reasonable institution, some leeway in scheduling an interview. I think that is especially true in a case like this. Even more so if you were presenting, though you don't indicate that you are.

And it might even turn out that some institutions will also have faculty at the conference, making for an additional opportunity.

And if you get an especially hopeful response to your application there is no reason you can't cancel the attendance at the conference, assuming you are *not* presenting.

But, I'll also note that many US colleges are on break during that period and so are unlikely to be holding interviews then. Not impossible, but less likely than during the coming term.